# I build solc from source v0.4.18 but can't not use it to compile solidity. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: solidity, compiler

```
$ solc  --bin -o ./contracts SimpleStore.sol

Warning: This is a pre-release compiler version, please do not use it in product                                                                                                 ion.
SimpleStore.sol:1:1: Error: Source file requires different compiler version (cur                                                                                                 rent compiler is 0.4.18-develop.2018.12.6+commit.9cf6e910.Linux.g++ - note that                                                                                                  nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
```

Comment: Can you provide the pragma directive of your smart contract? Something like `pragma solidity <version>`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you compiled a nightly commit, and the pragma requires the 0.4.18 version or later. You can use a later version of solidity, or use [the release version](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.18)

Remember that `^0.4.18` means "0.4.18 or later", so you can simply use a later version, and that would be more secure. Just know that if you choose a 0.5.x version things may fail, since there where breaking changes, like going from function scoping to block scoping.